# Teradata 15: Failed [5315 : HY000] An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION access to DBC.RoleMembersV.RoleName

Tags: permissions, teradata

I am using Teradata 15.  Using a powerful database user sysdba, I created the following view:

```
REPLACE VIEW DBA_TABLES_TEST.ROLE_ALL_APP_USERS AS
SELECT   A.ROLENAME 
   FROM  DBC.ROLEMEMBERSV A
   WHERE A.ROLENAME LIKE 'TG%';
```

I got the following errors:

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5315 : HY000] An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION access to DBC.RoleMembersV.RoleName. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.015 

STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.
```

Then I used DBC to grant sysdba the select right, but try the view again, it did not work:

```
GRANT SELECT ON DBC TO SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Any idea how can I grant the correct rights to sysdba?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Oh, I just figured out the correct grant statement.  All my views are working now.  I can audit my user/database/role permissions using these views.

```
GRANT SELECT ON DBC TO DBA_TABLES_TEST WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Always nice when you figure it out yourself, eh!